# How to create own decoder for custom error handling?

Tags: scala, akka, json4s

I have created custom errors in my app:

```
sealed trait DataError extends Product with Serializable
final case class DataNotFound(ex: String) extends DataError
final case class DataStorageError(ex: String) extends DataError
```

And I have created simple decoder for json responses:

```
DataNotFound(code, message) => HttpResponse(StatusCodes.NotFound, entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, s"""{"code":"$code", "message":"No data found: $message"}"""))
DataStorageError(message) => HttpResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, s"$message"))
```

But as you see, this is a poor solution in my opinion. I would like to use json4s formats to parse error messages into jsons automatically, instead of writing manual strings.

I tried to do something like:

```
implicit val format = jsonFormat2(DataNotFound)
```

But it did not work in this case.

What is the best way to do it to get same results? Is it possible or maybe my solution is fine?

Comment: It should be part of this: https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!